# Migración de contenedores Docker de un servidor A, a un servidor B

Tags: docker, odoo

Hola a todos y a todas.

Tengo la aplicación Odoo funcionando mediante Docker en un servidor A y necesito migrar los contenedores y toda su información a otro servidor B.

La aplicación Odoo se compone de:

- 1 contenedor para la BD postgres (odoo_db)
- 1 contenedor con la aplicación Odoo (odoo_web)

Para migrar los contenedores, hago lo siguiente:

1. En el servidor A, se hace un *commit* de los 2 contenedores:

> ```
> docker commit db5f8856a16b odoo_db
> docker commit 494b8391becf odoo_web
> ```

2. Se hace un *save* de los 2 contenedores:

> ```
> docker save -o odoo_db.tar odoo_db
> docker save -o odoo_web.tar odoo_web
> ```

3. En el servidor B, se hace un *load* de los 2 contenedores:

> ```
> docker load -i odoo_db.tar
> docker load -i odoo_web.tar
> ```

4. Se hace un *run* de los 2 contenedores introduciendo la información por defecto de postgres y aplicando el parámetro –-link para volver a linkar los 2 contenedores.

> ```
> docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name odoo_db odoo_db:latest
> docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo_web --link odoo_db:db -t odoo_web:latest
> ```

No funciona correctamente. Cuando accedo al programa (http://localhost:8069) no se reconoce la base de datos antigua.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer la migración correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Las migraciones más correctas en Docker se hacen copiando los volumenes externos con los datos a la ubicación remota.

Cuando lanzas un contenedor, la idea es añadir el parámetro `-v /carpeta_host:/carpeta_container` para poder tener los datos de la aplicación guardados en una carpeta. De esta forma, solo tienes que copiar la carpeta y volver a lanzar el contenedor con los mismos parámetros.

De todas maneras, si ya tienes los contenedores creados sin volúmenes, prueba a apagar los containers antes de hacerles el commit, para asegurarnos de que no queda el archivo en disco en un estado incosistente.